# Postfix + Dovecot + Sieve - CC and BCC redirects won't works

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot, sieve

guys!

I have a CentOS web server with ISPConfig, this server has been running without any problems for over a year, included with the email service (postfix + dovecot + sieve).

However, a new need arose for a client that is sending copies of emails to other accounts (which are inside the server itself)

I've been debating with Sieve for a couple of days.
When we configure some redirection in ispconfig, either CC or BCC, the email arrives for the main account, but the account that should receive the copy does not receive the message.

Below the log of the server (Maillog) referring to the delivery of the email (I just changed the email addresses to protect them):

```
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Si022014: w2L1v4Sj022014: DSN: Service unavailable
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 postfix/smtpd[21955]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<> to=<lxxxxx@agxxxxxxx.com.br> proto=ESMTP helo=<srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br>
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Sj022014: to=lxxxxx@agxxxxxxx.com.br, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=33744, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.7.1, stat=Service unavailable
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Sj022014: w2L1v4Sk022014: return to sender: Service unavailable
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 postfix/smtpd[21955]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br>: Helo command rejected: Host not found; from=<> to=<postmaster@srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br> proto=ESMTP helo=<srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br>
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Sk022014: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=34768, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.7.1, stat=Service unavailable
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Sj022014: Losing ./qfw2L1v4Sj022014: savemail panic
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 sendmail[22014]: w2L1v4Sj022014: SYSERR(vmail): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 dovecot: lda(sales@xxxxxxx.com): Error: Sendmail process terminated abnormally, exit status 69
Mar 20 22:57:05 srv-exwb01 dovecot: lda(sales@xxxxxxx.com): Error: sieve: msgid=<EC64216D-EE77-4791-8915-4A699CAD1EDF@agxxxxxxx.com.br>: failed to redirect message to <marketing@xxxxxxx.com> (refer to server log for more information)
```

This is the sieve log for the account:

```
sieve: info: started log at Mar 20 22:11:48.
error: msgid=<ABE38407-805D-4D24-96E5-1EFD09409C12@agxxxxxxx.com.br>: failed to redirect message to <iteles@yyyyyyyyyy.com.br> (refer to server log for more information).
sieve: info: started log at Mar 20 22:25:24.
error: msgid=<63FFBE47-3494-4E5E-970C-5A4BE87DC94E@agxxxxxxx.com.br>: failed to redirect message to <iteles@yyyyyyyyyy.com.br> (refer to server log for more information).
sieve: info: started log at Mar 20 22:39:31.
error: msgid=<D2C0A66A-7B28-4224-A0D9-C453A845C855@agxxxxxxx.com.br>: failed to redirect message to <marketing@xxxxxxx.com> (refer to server log for more information).
sieve: info: started log at Mar 20 22:57:05.
error: msgid=<EC64216D-EE77-4791-8915-4A699CAD1EDF@agxxxxxxx.com.br>: failed to redirect message to <marketing@xxxxxxx.com> (refer to server log for more information).
```

**Additional information:** The server has been configured using this tutorial:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-centos-7-apache-mysql-php-pureftpd-postfix-dovecot-and-ispconfig/

Would anyone have any idea what might be happening?
Thank you in advance for your attention.

Comment: "Helo command rejected: Host not found", helo=<srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br>. The mail server can't resolve your systems hostname. Can't you fix that?

Comment: The mail server may do a reverse lookup of your ip address and find it does not resolve to  srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.
I had noticed this error message too, but I did not understand much, since I have configured the PTR record for this server, but one thing I noticed now that I did not notice when I run nslookup on another machine for the IP of my server, it resolves the name of my nameserver (ns1.eximiaweb.com.br), even though the name is not configured in the PTR register, would it be convenient to change the name ns1 to solve the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Or can I simple create a new A record with the server name?

Comment: Strange, just tested your ip and got: 220 srv-exwb01.eximiaweb.com.br ESMTP Postfix.  That would mean the mail server itself has a dns problem or it doesn't see your IP. Ah, it says the mail comes from "127.0.0.1".

Comment: My server responds by all services (email, dns, web and mysql), then the routing, theoretically, would be done inside the server itself .. lol
I'll supplement the question with the DNS configs of the main domain.

Comment: Well ... I seem to have been able to find the problem.
I had the PTR registry configured in my Bind, but in the company interface that provides me the cloud server the reverse dns for my ip was configured for ns1, I changed there to the name of my server, and I did a test, not me returned the same error, I will test a few more times and post here the result if someone else has the same problem. Tks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well...

I think I was able to solve the problem with a help from my friend @Gerard H. Pille, as mentioned in the comments, I have the PTR record in my bind, but as @Gerard H. Pille noted, even with this record, the reverse dns it was not working.

Then scouring the panel of the company that provides me the cloud instance, I found a reverse dns being pointed to a different name from my server (ns1.eximiaweb.com.br), and it was here that Sieve was getting lost, even internally he was trying to find online and can't find it. What I did was to change this configuration from ns1.eximia ... to the server name (which is present in the hosts file).

This solved the problem, I found it interesting to register, because it could be that someone else has the same problem.

Thanks for the help, @Gerard H. Pille!

Comment: You're welcome, but go easy on the butter.